# Glyphicon and Button Text should be side by side

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am trying to place a glyphicon inside a button control but the button text and glyphicon don't come in the same line. The button text comes slightly below and is not parallel with the glyphicon

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="my button" style="border: 0px">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="color:#a0a0a0; font-size: 30px" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    My Button Text
</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there should be `vertical-align: middle;` to glyphicon span where you have placed inline CSS

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="my button" style="border: 0px">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="color:#a0a0a0; font-size: 30px; vertical-align: middle;" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       My Button Text
</button>
```

That's it :)

Comment: Welcome :) Then I think you should approve my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap grid system and css like following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="my button" style="border: 0px">
    <div class="col-md-2">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="color:#a0a0a0; font-size: 30px" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-10" style="padding-top:5px;  margin-left: -4px">
   My Button Text
   </div>
</button>
```

Comment: I think this is pretty long solution ... Having vertical align middle will solve the problem instead of grids..

Comment: Solving the issue by using any method is not good way so far ..  Solution should be feasible .. There are other methods too like wrapping text in span and then having margin from top but that is not a good way ...